# Google Cloud Speech to Text API - Speaker Diarization

Tags: node.js, node-modules, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

When i am trying to do a speech to text transcribe of a live phone call using web socket.

Already included

```
const Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1beta1;

const speech = new Speech.SpeechClient();
```

With following config.

```
encoding: 'LINEAR16',
sampleRateHertz: 8000,
languageCode: 'en-US',
useEnhanced: true,
enableSpeakerDiarization: true,
diarizationSpeakerCount: 2,
enableWordConfidence: true,
model: `phone_call`,
```

I am getting following response

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "words": [],
          "transcript": " what I'm trying to do is",
          "confidence": 0.778500497341156
        }
      ],
      "isFinal": true,
      "stability": 0
    }
  ],
  "error": null,
  "speechEventType": "SPEECH_EVENT_UNSPECIFIED"
}
```

Do you guys know why i am not getting speaker diarization in the response from the google cloud for the above config?

Comment: I think we are going to need more context.  While I dislike posts with lots of code, perhaps post your code as an attachment or as a link.  We are likely going to want to see the whole context of how you are processing the audio.  Also a written example of what the audio contains and what you anticipate the output to be.